# Rails show views from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby on Rails application

I have a page Aboutus - This has a Controller and View. Has no model.

I have a Comments model (generated by the rails generate scaffold comment) - This has a Controller, view, model

On my Aboutus page, I want to show the "Comments" from the comments model, so I am thinking of using the Comments index action (to list comments) and new action (to create new comments) on my Aboutus page.

I am having trouble getting this right.

This is what I did:
Aboutus controller, I added
`redirect_to :controller => "comments", :action => "index"`

Aboutus views, I added
`<%= render 'comments/index' %>`

It doesnt work, gives me Undefined redirect_to and nil object @comments errors.
Could you advise me
1. A proper way to do this
2. Syntax
3. Any thing to do to config.rb ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to create a partial that you use to render the comments in the comments index view, and also in your view for the aboutus page

```
# in about_us and in 'comments#index'
<%= render :partial 'path/to/_partial' %>

#in the about_us controller, or whatever controller dispatches the about us view

@comments = Comment.all.where(:my_conditions)

#partial view

<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
..
<% end %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be Comment.where(:my_conditions)? When each is called in the view, it'll execute the query.

Comment: good point. I forgot about Rails 3 and lazy loading of collections.